# Apps Script: How to force entry of cell value that is not committed yet (enter key is not yet pressed)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to make an input form in Google Sheets. It will then be shared to people who will use the program.

Only that after typing their entry in the Remarks field (and without pressing the Enter Key), they might click the Save button immediately.

My script cannot read whatever is entered in the Remarks cell if the Enter Key (or arrow, etc) is not yet pressed.

I basically want whatever is entered in the remarks field committed when the user clicks on the Save Button. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your current issue of `My script cannot read whatever is entered in the Remarks cell if the Enter Key (or arrow, etc) is not yet pressed.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike, thx for the response.

The issue: The user might press the Save Button immediately after typing something in the remarks. They need to press Enter Key first before pressing the Save Button.

The Goal: Force commit whatever is entered in the Remarks field, so that even if they press the Save button, whatever is in the Remarks field will also be saved.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `They need to press Enter Key first before pressing the Save Button.`. And, I'm worried that I might not be able to have understood your showing image. Can I ask you about your showing image? That is a text input tag of HTML?

Comment: @Tanaike, that image is a sheet in the Google Sheets. The text field is actually a merged cell from C20:M20. It is NOT HTML.  Btw, your English is fine, I clearly understand you :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `that image is a sheet in the Google Sheets. The text field is actually a merged cell from C20:M20. It is NOT HTML.`, in this case, how about using OnEdit trigger? When OnEdit trigger is used, when the value is put to a cell, the trigger is fired. I thought that this situation might be able to be used. How about this?

Comment: "when the value is put to a cell, the trigger is fired" I thought of this too, but the value in the text field is not yet committed. So the OnEdit() trigger will not be fired because the user has not changed cell yet (example: the user has not pressed the Enter key or any Arrow keys). Imagine it this way, they typed their remarks, and immediately pressed the Save Button (thinking that whatever they typed is already in the Sheet, BUT it is not yet saved/entered in the sheet, they just typed)!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about the following flow? 1. Prepare 2 functions. One is used for showing the warning. Another is used for running "SAVE" process (this is your script.). When the value was put into the cell, by OnEdit trigger, the function of "SAVE" button is changed from "warning" to the "SAVE" process. By this, "SAVE" process can be correctly run. If this was not your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks a lot for your replies and patience. I thank you for your advice. I will try to implement this. Thank you again!